# Was torricelli right on atmosphere as energy to push mercury level up in barometer?

Tags: atmospheric-science

How below image can be explained in regard to Torricelli's logic on atmospheric pressure. Also, If we close the pot from the top and pressurize it to 1 kg/cm2 g, what happens with mercury level in the tube?

[image]

Comment: The atmosphere does not provide _energy_ to push the mercury up. The energy was provided by the hand that lifted the tube into position after filling it. The atmosphere provides the _force_ to keep the mercury from falling back down. But no energy is needed to maintain force on a thing if the force does not cause the thing to move.

Comment: Whether both figures showing 760mmHg mercury level are correct? if so, how different dia pots resultant force p*PI()r2 (r=100 & r=200) gives same result?